# Laravel not detecting multiple file uploads

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to upload multiple images in one request with Laravel. However, it only seems to be seeing one file regardless of the fact that my file input has multiple files attached.

Markup:

```
<input class="file-input" type="file" name="fileUpload" multiple>
```

Controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
'fileUpload' => 'image|nullable',

 ...

foreach ($request->file('fileUpload') as $image) {
    dd('stop');
}
dd('fail');
```

In this case, it always returns "fail". However, if I try to just `$request->file('fileUpload')` it will return to me a single file, like so: [image: a single file]

Comment: Off the top of my mind, for PHP to handle "array" of anything in POST requests, it has to have `[]` at the end of the name. Could you maybe try naming your field `fileUpload[]`?

(inexact) source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php and also this one: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#114235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like multiple selects, if you want to send multiple values then you need to use the array syntax in your input’s `name` attribute. So it should be `fileUpload[]` instead of just `fileUpload`

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the input **fileUpload** to **fileUpload[]** :

```
<input class="file-input" type="file" name="fileUpload[]" multiple />
```

Also in the controller for validating multiple fields, change **'fileUpload'** to **'fileUpload.*'** :

```
$this->validate($request, [
                           'fileUpload.*' => 'image|nullable',
```